# ReCaptcha won't validate

Tags: php, validation, recaptcha

My reCaptcha is not validating. It let's me through no matter what. It is sending email and redirecting to thank you page, but not validating reCaptcha. What am I missing? Here is my PHP code. I didn't show it but I do have the proper code in the head and form tags (copied/pasted from reCAPTCHA). Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $secret = 'MY SECRET KEY';
    $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $url = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteip");
    $result = json_decode($url, TRUE);
   if ($result['success'] == 1){
   }
    }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $emailbody = 'Name: '.$_POST['name']."\n"
    .'Phone: '.$_POST['phone']."\n"
    .'Email: '.$_POST['email']."\n"
    .'Message: '.$_POST['message'];     
    mail('myemail@mydomain.com', 'More Information', $emailbody);
    header('location: thankyou.php');


exit();
    }

?>
```

Comment: question: why are you using 2x `f(isset($_POST['submit']))`? and where's the form for this? use error reporting also. best I can offer

Comment: Whatever I have there is what I got from videos. I am a newbie. I am open to corrections for sure. Do I need to show the form if all else is working but the recaptcha?

Comment: it seems you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/q/40400611/1415724 being closely related. So, I don't know what the form looks like or if the key you're trying to get is valid.

Comment: My problem is I get the email/redirect to work then when I add the recaptcha it won't work.

Comment: you've been given an answer below. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to let them know about it. It basically removed one the extra conditional statement that I asked you as to why you are using those.

Answer (score 0):

You are validating, however, you are processing after validating, but outside the if statement, where you determine whether or not the validation was a success...

This code can be changed to:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$secret = 'MY SECRET KEY';
$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$url = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteip");
$result = json_decode($url, TRUE);
if ($result['success'] == 1){

$emailbody = 'Name: '.$_POST['name']."\n"
.'Phone: '.$_POST['phone']."\n"
.'Email: '.$_POST['email']."\n"
.'Message: '.$_POST['message'];     
mail('myemail@mydomain.com', 'More Information', $emailbody);
header('location: thankyou.php');
exit();
} else {
 // captcha failed
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Now it is validating (I think) but not redirecting.

Comment: where I inserted "// captcha failed", replace that with "echo 'captcha failed';" if the page echoes it out, then the validation failed.

Comment: Now it refreshes the page and shows the echo "captcha failed" at the top for the page and doesn't not show the form at all.

Comment: If the email and everything works, then the issue lies with the recaptcha. Have you made sure, that the secret key and the recaptcha name in text box in the html form is correct in comparison to the php code? You will have to do some research on the recaptcha.

Comment: The email/redirecting was working until that last "fix". Ha. I will recheck the recaptcha info.